# Components displayed vertically after adding DatePicker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

After I've added DatePickers to a simple form, all components got placed vertically, while I would prefer them to be placed horizontally. Is there any parameter that should be set to make this work, or I must play a bit with CSS?

```
<MuiThemeProvider>
    <div>
        <TextField hintText="Enter text"/>
        <DatePicker hintText="Date from" container="inline" mode="landscape" />
        <DatePicker hintText="Date to" container="inline" mode="landscape" />
        <IconButton>
            <img src="img/ic_search_black_24px.svg"/>
        </IconButton>
    </div>
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each DatePicker, set the style to:

```
style={{ display: 'inline-block' }}
```